# Docker issue while installing

Tags: docker

While installing Docker in my laptop having Windows 10,it shows an error

**Docker for Windows requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 10586, or Windows server 2016 RTM to run**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your powershell console and run:

```
get-computerinfo -property windows*
```

check what version of windows 10 you have. the mesaage is quite clear, you cannot install docker for windows because you don't have a valid version of windows 10.

from their web page:

> The current version of Docker for Windows runs on 64bit Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise and Education (1607 Anniversary Update, Build 14393 or later).

Comment: Thank you sir for your help....Now i have installed **docker tool kit** in my laptop....Can you please help me to understand what is the difference between **docker for windows** and **docker tool kit for windows**

Comment: Hi. Check this web page: **https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/**
Everything is well explained there.